# Extracting information from page source

Tags: vb.net

I hope the title is a good one. I use this code to upload source page in `Page` string.

```
    Dim Page As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/3M23WLCdaBVXaAjG3CuVUDoAKgpd3xiv8V/")
    Console.WriteLine(Page)
```

The source page:

> view-source:https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/bc1qwsn95n9ddnxq8aduxnwp6tdc6gagj02kqqew7d/

How can I get this information from the source page written one by one in a msgbox?
MsgBox like: `Recivied: 0.0 BTC` ; `Sent: 0.0 BTC` ; `Balance: 0.0 BTC`

```html
<ul>
<li>
<span class="dash-label">Received</span><br>
0.0 BTC
</li>
<li>
<span class="dash-label">Sent</span><br>
0.0 BTC
</li>
<li>
<span class="dash-label">Balance</span><br>
0.0 BTC
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to write a code to get the received bitcoin number but it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub StartBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartBTN.Click
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim Page As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/3M23WLCdaBVXaAjG3CuVUDoAKgpd3xiv8V/")
    'Console.WriteLine(Page)
    Dim ReciviedDelimStart As String = "<span class=""dash-label"">Received</span><br>"
    Dim ReciviedDelimEnd As String = "</li>"
    Dim Find_ReciviedStart As Integer = Page.IndexOf(ReciviedDelimStart)
    Dim Find_ReciviedEnd As Integer = Page.IndexOf(ReciviedDelimEnd)

    If Find_ReciviedStart > -1 AndAlso Find_ReciviedEnd > -1 Then
        Dim Result As String = Mid(Page, Find_ReciviedStart + ReciviedDelimStart.Length + 1, Find_ReciviedEnd - Find_ReciviedStart - ReciviedDelimStart.Length) 
        MessageBox.Show("Recivied: " + Result) 'THE OUTPUT MUST BE: "Recivied: 0.0 BTC"
    End If
End Sub
```

I also tried to make a similar code from where the program obtains from the source of the page the link to the QR code of the bitcoin address and `Picture_BTC_QR` receives the picture with the QR code

```
Private Sub StartBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartBTN.Click
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim Page As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/3M23WLCdaBVXaAjG3CuVUDoAKgpd3xiv8V/")
    'Console.WriteLine(Page)
    Dim QR_DelimStart As String = "<img src=""//"
    Dim QR_DelimEnd As String = """"
    Dim QR_FindStart As Integer = Page.IndexOf(QR_DelimStart)
    Dim QR_FindEnd As Integer = Page.IndexOf(QR_DelimEnd)
    
    If QR_FindStart > -1 AndAlso QR_FindEnd > -1 Then
        Dim Result As String = Mid(Page, QR_FindStart + QR_DelimStart.Length + 1, QR_FindEnd - QR_FindStart - QR_DelimStart.Length)
        Picture_BTC_QR.Load("https://" + Result)
        'MessageBox.Show("https://" + Result) 'THE OUTPUT MUST BE: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=bitcoin%3Abc1qwsn95n9ddnxq8aduxnwp6tdc6gagj02kqqew7d&choe=UTF-8&chs=300x300"
    End If 
End Sub
```

The error I get is:

> "System.ArgumentException: 'Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero."

I did not find a solving solution. That's why I decided to post here, maybe someone can help me solve the error or with a code to help me with what I want to get. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML with string manipulation functions? Why not use an HTML parser, which is built exactly for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know how to program very well

Comment: Please don't post nonsense answers to bump your question.

Comment: Anyone who can help me? I need urgently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use Regex to match the text. First add this line at begginning:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then match like this:

```
Dim Re As Regex = New Regex("(.*)\s+BTC")
Dim Matches As MatchCollection = Re.Matches(Page)
For Each Match As Match In Matches
  Console.WriteLine(Match.Value)
Next
```

Comment: Something works but not perfectly. This is my Console output: https://textuploader.com/1p4e3